# ADA integer types?

Tags: ada

[image: Question here]

i) line 9 there will be error `My_DigitT` a new type,
so MD cannot be assign to D.

ii) line 10 there will out of bound exception,
you can eliminate this by change `type Digit is mod 10`.

Can someone help verify these answers?

for question i)

```
Digit_T is range 0..9; 
type My_Digit_T is new Digit_T;
 D : Digit_T; 
MD : My_Digit_T(Digit_T); 
begin
 D := 0; 
MD := D;
 D := D + 5 + 5;
 end;
```

It this solution I converted MD type to Digit_T this should work?By the way I tired an online compiler im getting error rextester.com/CFFFCP14315 –

Comment: 1) doesn't answer : 2 ways to fix the error. 2) doesn't name the exception that will actually be raised.

Comment: Please post the code, not an image of the code.

Comment: Your answers appear correct, however you have not explained two different ways to fix the compilation error.

Comment: @JimRogers Hi Jim, Thanks

Comment: @johnKDOEALLISSON: A review of Ada _type conversion_ may help you identify two different ways to fix the error.

Comment: @trashgod                                                         
 type Digit_T is range 0..9;
type My_Digit_T is new Digit_T;
D : Digit_T;
MD : My_Digit_T(Digit_T);
begin
D := 0;
MD := D;
D := D + 5 + 5;
end;                                                                                                                            It this solution I converted MD type to Digit_T this should work?By the way I tired an online compiler im getting https://rextester.com/CFFFCP14315

Comment: @JimRogers type Digit_T is range 0..9;
type My_Digit_T is new Digit_T;
D : Digit_T;
MD : My_Digit_T(Digit_T);
begin
D := 0;
MD := D;
D := D + 5 + 5;
end;                                                                                                                            It this solution I converted MD type to Digit_T this should work?By the way I tired an online compiler im getting https://rextester.com/CFFFCP14315

Comment: @johnKDOEALLISSON: Again, please [edit] your question to show revised code. Ada [_type conversion_](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-6.html) has examples of _value_ conversion at the bottom of the page. Another approach is shown there, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@johnKDOEALLISSON I am responding to your question with an answer because you need more detailed help.
Your changed code looks like:

```
procedure Main is
   type Digit_T is range 0..9;
   type My_Digit_T is new Digit_T;
   D : Digit_T;
   MD : My_Digit_T(Digit_T); -- This line is not correct.
begin
   D := 0;
   MD := D;
   D := D + 5 + 5;
end Main;
```

The GNAT compiler I use reports the following issues:

[image: Compiler Warnings]

One cannot convert a type to another type (Line 5).
Assigning MD  := D causes the warnings for line 8. The range of Digit_T is 0 through 9. The expression D := D + 5 + 5; generates a value of 10, which is not within the valid set of values for Digit_T.

If you want to assign D to MD they must be members of the same type, or D must be converted to an instance of My_Digit_T. Note that you can convert an instance to another type, but you have tried to convert a type to another type.
Another solution is to make My_Digit_T a subtype of Digit_T rather than making it a separate type.

A solution using a proper type conversion for the variable D is:

```
procedure Main is
   type Digit_T is mod 10;
   type My_Digit_T is new Digit_T;
   D : Digit_T;
   MD : My_Digit_T;
begin
   D := 0;
   MD := My_Digit_T(D);
   D := D + 5 + 5;
end Main;
```

Type Digit_T has been changed to a modular type. Modular types employ modular arithmetic so that all addition operations result in a value within the declared range of values. In this case the range of valid values is still 0..9, but 5 + 5 results in 0 (10 mod 10 is 0).

I leave the solution using a subtype up to you.